# Is there a way to get the outfit on the box-art?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

On the cover box-art of AC:NL, the boy character has an outfit that has caught my eye. I assumed that the outfit would appear in the Able Sister's shop sooner or later, but it hasn't. Is there a way I can get this outfit?

[image: Animal Crossing Box-art]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you definitely can get the outfit, but it can take some time for the Able Sisters to have all the proper pieces. I bought the hat and shirt just a few days between each other, but I had to check the store every day for almost 2 weeks until the pants were on sale. You'll also need the Kicks store unlocked (by spending 8,000 Bells at the Able Sisters) to obtain the shoes as well, of course.

Comment: I'd suggest posting what the pieces are.

Comment: Of course! I'll edit once I can get to my 3DS.